# Oracle SQL : sort row with delimited string

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, row

My SQL query (in Oracle 11g) returns a column like this:

```
31132,11100,44232
25464,89453,15686
21561,68547,51612
```

I want to order these cells, I mean:

```
11100,31132,44232
15686,25464,89453
21561,51612,68547
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the values guaranteed to always be three five-digit numbers?

Comment: Show us the query.

Comment: Add more context...do you want to keep the initial numbers of rows ? Do you always have 3 comma-separated values, do you want to keep 3 comma separated values per row, etc... a lot of questions really.

Comment: No. The values between the comma are always numbers, but the size is variable

Comment: In a cell there are always 3 comma-separated values (numbers). They are not always five-digit numbers but at least 1 digit. yes i want to keep 3 comma separated values per row. sorry my english is not the best...

Comment: the query is SELECT * FROM table1

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma delimited values in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR to pull out the individual numbers from each row, and then use LISTAGG to rejoin them in the desired order -- something like the below:

```
WITH 
  T (N) AS --TEST DATA
    (SELECT '31132,11100,44232' FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT '25464,89453,15686' FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT '21561,68547,51612' FROM DUAL),
  T1 (N1) AS --USE THIS BELOW TO SEPARATE OUT FIRST/SECOND/THIRD VALUE FROM EACH ROW
    (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 3 FROM DUAL),
  SEPARATED (RN,N) AS 
    (SELECT RN,REGEXP_SUBSTR(N,'[^,]+',1,T1.N1) N FROM --GET THE VALUES FROM EACH ROW WITH AN ACCOMPANYING ROW NUMBER SO WE CAN REGROUP THEM BELOW
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1) RN ,N FROM T),T1)
SELECT LISTAGG(N,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY N) FROM SEPARATED GROUP BY RN; --USE LISTAGG TO REJOIN THE SEPARATED VALUES IN THE DESIRED ORDER
```