# Apply order by in comma separated string in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have one of the column in oracle table which has below value :

```
select csv_val from my_table where date='09-OCT-18';

output
==================
50,100,25,5000,1000
```

I want this values to be in ascending order with select query, output would looks like :

```
 output
 ==================
 25,50,100,1000,5000
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678782/oracle-sql-sort-row-with-delimited-string) link, but looks like it has some restriction on number of digits.

Comment: Fix your data model so you are not storing lists of numbers as a string.

Comment: Unfortunately data already there in legacy tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort delimited separated values in a string with (Oracle) SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808325/sort-delimited-separated-values-in-a-string-with-oracle-sql)

Comment: In the linked thread, is the limitation on number of DIGITS or on the number of TOKENS (NUMBERS)? What is the data type of CSV_VAL - it is VARCHAR2 or is it CLOB? Then: can your input string have null tokens (two consecutive commas, to represent a NULL), and if so, what is the desired handling in the output?

Comment: Regarding the "legacy tables" comment - that explains the input, but not the output. Why do you need the OUTPUT as a comma-separated string? Then: if you need the tokens in increasing order, why don't you execute a one-time UPDATE to change the stored strings? (And modify the process that inserts or updates the table so that in the future all CSV_VALUE values are already ordered.) Even if you have to put up with legacy tables, you could create a view (perhaps materialized) where the values are separated on individual rows. You shouldn't have to put up with this in every query you write.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I made you a modified version of the answer you linked to that can handle an arbitrary (hardcoded) number of commas. It's pretty heavy on CTEs. As with most LISTAGG answers, it'll have a 4000-char limit. I also changed your regexp to be able to handle null list entries, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464699/3061852).

```
WITH 
  T (N) AS --TEST DATA
    (SELECT '50,100,25,5000,1000' FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT '25464,89453,15686' FROM DUAL
    UNION
    SELECT '21561,68547,51612' FROM DUAL
    ),
  nums (x) as -- arbitrary limit of 20, can be changed
    (select level from dual connect by level <= 20),
  splitstr (N, x, substring) as
    (select N, x, regexp_substr(N, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, x, NULL, 1)
    from T
    inner join nums on x <= 1 + regexp_count(N, ',')
    order by N, x)
select N, listagg(substring, ',') within group (order by to_number(substring)) as sorted_N
from splitstr
group by N
;
```

Probably it can be improved, but eh...

Comment: Did you test your query? The outputs all have one fewer token than the inputs. (The reason probably has to do with `x <= regexp_count`; that should be `x <= 1 + regexp_count`). Then: you mention handling `null`; but `listagg` removes `null`, so that is not a complete handling of nulls.

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally deleted the `+1` when editing for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sample data you posted, relatively simple query would work (you need lines 3 - 7). If data doesn't really look like that, query might need adjustment.

```
SQL>  with my_table (csv_val) as
  2    (select '50,100,25,5000,1000' from dual)
  3  select listagg(token, ',') within group (order by to_number(token)) result
  4  from (select regexp_substr(csv_val, '[^,]+', 1, level) token
  5        from my_table
  6        connect by level <= regexp_count(csv_val, ',') + 1
  7       );

RESULT
-------------------------
25,50,100,1000,5000

SQL>
```